# Rails - ActiveRecord where with multiple conditions in nested routes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am building a website where a user can create a project. Each project contains several papers. Each paper can be reviewed by answering several questions.

I have four models (User, Project, Paper, Questions).

In `questions_controller` I created an action `replies` with the aim of selecting all the replies with specific `project_id` and `paper_id`.

In the object `@replies`, I want to select all the papers and project with the `project_id` and `paper_id` displayed in the URL.

http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/3/papers/2/questions/1/replies

I want to select all the replies with `project_id == 3` and `paper_id == 2`

To do so, I wrote this code:

**questions_controller.rb**

```
  def replies
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @paper = Paper.find(params[:paper_id])
    @replies = Question.where("project_id = ? AND paper_id = ?", params[:project_id], params[:paper_id])
  end
```

And passed `@replies` in:

**views/questions/replies.html.erb**

```
<% @replies.each do |reply| %>
  <%= reply %>
<% end %>
```

**However**, it is not working. In fact, my query in `@replies` is not passing anything in my **views/questions/replies.html.erb**.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects do
    resources :papers do
      resources :questions do
        collection do
          get 'replies'
        end
      end
    end
  end
devise_for :users
root to: 'pages#home'
```

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :papers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :questions
end
```

**paper.rb**

```
class Paper < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :questions
  has_one_attached :paper_pdf
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :paper
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :projects
  has_many :questions
end
```

Comment: You don't say the actual problem. Do you have any error besides the `raise` ? If you have no error then the problem is not code related. Do you actually have `questions` stored in the database for paper 2 ? ... Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Show your models, show the actual error. Also, using more than 2 levels of nested resources is disencouraged, you sure have a way to simplify your routes. I'm guessing you need to join the tables to do those queries, read about activerecord's `joins`, `includes` and `references`.

Comment: with the way you have currently set up your routes, you will also be required to have a question_id in the path. But I don't think  you actually want the question id. you change the routes to something like this and perhaps it will work out of the box: `resources :questions do
  collection do
    get 'replies'
  end
end` --- don't forget to ensure that the questions are nested within the projects and papers resources correctly, and lastly, I recommend using shallow nesting.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I think you are right. I do not need to have `replies` after `question_id`. I think I need it like this `/papers/1/questions/replies` because I need all the replies (of the questions) for a specific papers. I fixed the routes as you suggested however I am still stuck. In my **questions_controller** i have added an action `replies` with `@replies = Question.where("project_id = ? AND paper_id = ?", params[:project_id], params[:paper_id])` but it still does not take find the @replies. So I guess my query is wrong.

Comment: @Maxence @arieljuod I added the information you asked on my questions and made it more clear. My problem is that the query at `@replies`in my **question_controller** does not retrieve anything. I want to retrieve (all the answered questions of a specific paper in a specific project). Questions are created because i verigy it via `rails console --> Question.all`and they exists with the right `project_id` and `paper_id` param,

Comment: One more question @FBSO : What is replies ? At the moment it seems replies are just questions : `@replies = Question.where("project_id = ? AND paper_id = ?", params[:project_id], params[:paper_id])` . Are replies questions ? Also your route specify the question : `http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/3/papers/2/questions/1/replies` Here you want question with id 1. Why in the controller you try to gather all questions (and name it `@replies`) for project 3 and papers 2 as specify a question in the route ?

Comment: @FBSO I recommend using shallow nesting to eliminate the redundant information in the routes: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: @Maxence Indeed, the `@replies` are just the `@questions`. I named it differently so I know `@replies`contails all the answered questions (by this I mean that `/questions/new` populates the questions database with some values. I want to retrieve in `@replies` these values specific for the paper and project I am in.

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems in your application design.

**First one** is the relationships of Questions :

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :paper
  belongs_to :project
end
```

I understand what you are trying to do here : a question can apply to different models : user, paper, project. Though there is a problem: the question can refer to only one of these models (it would be strange that a question applies to different objects at the same time). Then when you create a new question relating to user, the foreign keys for paper (`paper_id`) and project (`project_id`) will be empty.

This is not a good design. The way to do it is make the Question model a polymorphic model.

In case Question should only apply to papers, as you mention above, then why Question is child to other models than Paper ?

**Second problem** : you try to get Questions with two foreign keys :

`@replies = Question.where("project_id = ? AND paper_id = ?", params[:project_id], params[:paper_id])`

As I have described earlier in Problem 1, your Question model may have 3 foreign keys (to the 3 models it belongs to) but a question may not refer to more than one models at a time.

So when you try to get questions with these 2 foreign keys at the same time, you may get no answer to your query.

**Third problem**: use shallow nesting, your routes are too deep:

http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/3/papers/2/questions/1/replies

You don't need three levels of nesting here. You seem to be beginner so it may not feel intuitive, but check my suggestion below

**suggestion**:

If I read your question layout properly, questions only apply to Papers. 
Then if you want to get all questions related to this very paper, it is better to creat a new method `get replies` in this very model, not the question model.

Make it a member, not a collection :

routes :

```
...
resources :papers do
  member do
     get 'replies'
  end
end
...
```

then when your routes ends with `papers/5/replies`

You can trigger the below code in the paper controller:

```
def replies
  @paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
  @replies = @paper.questions
end
```

You notice my action code don't really need any of the preceding ids from the route. I only pick `params[:id]` which relates to the number 5. The id of paper model.

If you have deep nested routes, you realise that there is some data in the route that is unused. The really important data from the route is the last param. And maybe the preceding param.

If you need to make sure a paper belongs to the current user project, just compare the current user with the paper id like :

```
unless current_user.id == Paper.find(params[:id]).project.user.id
redirect_to root_path
```

And then that's it

Comment: Many thanks for this. What I do not get is the following: every-time the user submit a new answered question, I need to create an entity in the `question.rb` that contains the saved answers, plus the `id of the paper` it refers to, plus the `id of the project` in which the paper is in.
If I do what you are saying, I think I am not passing the right amount of parameters when I submit the form in `/questions/new`.

Comment: Why do you have to pass the project id ? If the questions are linked to a paper, you should only pass as foreign key the id of the paper. You can sure also pass the project id but it then makes the question the child of both models which I think is not right. 
Though if when you create a question, you add both foreign keys your original query should work. Just look into your database and check if the newly created question holds both foreign keys and rerun your original query. You should get something inside `@queries`

Comment: I say you don't need to add both foreign keys because it is useless. A paper is a child of a project. You dont need to add both paper and porject foreign keys inside your questions records. You can reach the parent of the paper easily by climbing the relationship tree: `@paper = Paper.find(params[:id])` `@project = @paper.project`

Comment: I want to pass the `project_id` because later I have to create two pages. One with the answers of each paper by each user.
One with the average of the answers of all the papers inside a project. Ex: `Project 1` contains `paper A` and `paper B`. A user answers the question in `paper A` with value 0-0-0. Then, he answer the question in `paper B` with value 0.5-0.5-0.5. Another user answers the question in `paper A` 1-1-1 and in `paper B` 0-0-0 (inside the same project). The average in paper A is 0.5-0.5-0.5, in Paper B 0.25-0-25-0-25. Therefore the average for the Project is 0.375-0.375-0.375